# Google Maps Javascript API Doesn't Respond to Touch Events in iOS 10

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I run a website with a number of custom Google Maps built in (showing various locations on a map after a search or generating directions to/from a location). I use Google Maps Javascript API for this. My users have started reporting that on iOS 10, these maps no longer respond to touch events -- they cannot pinch-to-zoom nor can they click on the "pins" on the map to open the location info balloons.

I've been searching all over for others who have had this issue to no avail. I found one StackOverflow question here (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DaiSdOgD0U4J:stackoverflow.com/questions/39401974/google-maps-javascript-doesnt-pan-or-zoom-in-ios-10+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), but it was downvoted, then deleted. (Why?) A fresh search today still shows that page, but it leads to a 404, making a search even more frustrating.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this a bug within the Google Maps API? I certainly can't find anything about that on their Developer website. Am I possibly doing something very wrong to lead to this? The code has worked for years and hasn't been modified in a few months now, so nothing changed on our end.

- We do use an API key in our requests
- I've tried switching from the
  current release version (3.25) to the current experimental version
  (3.26) with no changes in functionality.
- Users report this happens in at least both Safari and Chrome on iOS 10

Just hoping someone can provide any insight at all on the issue.

Comment: I'm joining you on this question. I also looked on google and found the 404 page you are talking about. This is a big issue because using IONIC apple devices under ios10 can't use our map and there is no way to understand why

Comment: Thank you! I am the one who asked the question. I waited for several days and no one responded to it except one down-voter. I thought it was only my problem so I deleted the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok here is how I did to fix this issue.
As a reminder i'm using AngularJS via the Ionic framework.
I was calling the map this way in my index.html :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=PUT_YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY_HERE&signed_in=true"></script>
```

It seams like signed_in feature of google map is adding a layer on the map that is not letting the map getting the X,Y of your screen touch position.

I just replaced by false to disable the signed_in feature and its working like a charm

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=PUT_YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY_HERE&signed_in=false"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome find! Seriously, great. I don't really love that we have to work around their bug like that, but well done noticing that issue. Frustrating that there has been almost nothing about the issue elsewhere online or from Google themselves. This is the most correct answer we're going to get for now I think.

Comment: I'm happy if it did it for you ! Took my hours to find out those kind of bug are really frustrating !

Comment: i have a theory on this, apparently the code that handles touches in safari has changed, before iOS10 the touch objects remained the same instances from touch start to touch end, that is not longer true, the identifiers are the same, but the touch events themselves are recreated every time the event handlers are called. this could, speculatively, cause some code in google maps to fail)

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the map initialization? Have you tried to change the gestureHandling properties to "greedy". By default it's "auto" and if the auto result in "cooperative" mode, all your one-finger touch gestures will pan the page. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions