# Google Maps JS API - Undefined 'point.pageX'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My Google Maps were working just fine until a few days ago when this error started to occur has soon as I interacted with the map.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluting 'point.pageX')

The error occurs when the code in common.js runs. This is a snippet from the javascript file

```
Bt=function(a,b,c){var d;a.Wo()?d=new window.MouseEvent(b,{bubbles:!0,cancelable:!0,view:window,detail:1,screenX:c.pageX,screenY:c.pageY,clientX:c.clientX,clientY:c.clientY}):(d=window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),d.initMouseEvent(b,!0,!0,window,1,c.pageX,c.pageY,c.clientX,c.clientY,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null));d.b=!0;(c=a.W)&&c.dispatchEvent&&c.dispatchEvent(d);_.z.trigger(a.A,b,d)};
```

The maps loads but then as soon as I start interacting with it (click on marker or panning) it throughs the error. Strangely the error isn't happening all the time - it occurs randomly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I started seeing this around the same time, but only (as far as I can tell) from an iPhone on iOS 10.0.1 - I can't seem to get this error to fire from desktop Chrome, FF or Safari. Did you learn more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what appears to be a related (albeit more general) post w/a solution that worked for me.

[Google Maps Javascript API Doesn't Respond to Touch Events in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540515/google-maps-javascript-api-doesnt-respond-to-touch-events-in-ios-10)

Change you call to googleapis.com to explicitly state `signed_in=false` where you likely have `signed_in=true`